# What does it mean if someone says "I'm good on something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

In the movie "Vacation Friends", One person tries to give another one an edible moss. But that person (receiver) says "Nah, I'm good on tree pubes."

It's obvious what the moss looks like. But how can one "be good on" it? What does "I'm good on..." mean here? None of the [customary definitions](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/good) seem to fit.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Have you looked up [*pube*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pube)? What do you think moss might look like? Or are you asking about the "I'm good on" part?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Exactly I'm asking about "I'm good on" part. Sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have enough of something. For example:

> "Should I bring something for the party? Some snacks?"
>
> "We're good on snacks but could use some more cups."

The joke here is that the person responding does not want to eat moss and says he has enough of "*tree pubes*" as a witty/pithy/dismissive retort.

Comment: So the person is saying that he's eaten enough moss and doesn't want any more?

Comment: That's the joke.

Comment: @StuartF In that case the joke should be explained. Jokes are on-topic, and answers shouldn't be oblique.

Answer (score -2):

If someone says that I am good at something that means that person has proper and accurate knowledge about that thing and he has confidence if some ask him about it he will give the answer to them.

Comment: "I'm good _at_ something" is a different usage from the example in this question.

Comment: @KillingTime But "I'm good on ancient history" is idiomatic and means what Devdham says.. Though not the usage OP exemplifies.